# why does dict.update(key=val) not use the string referenced by key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

As the title suggests, I am trying to update a dictionary using the `update()` method like in the following code block

```
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    new_dict.update(key=val)
```

If `my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` I would expect the result to be that `new_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` (assuming of course that new_dict is already defined). However, when executed, I instead get `new_dict = {'key': 2}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In `new_dict.update(key=val)`, `key` isn't your variable, its a named parameter in the keyword arguments in the `update` method. You can do `new_dict.update(my_dict)` and skip the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyword arguments always use the fixed identifier as the key. Use keyword expansion instead.

```
new_dict.update(**{key: val})
```

Or if `new_dict` really is a dict, just pass the dict itself.

```
new_dict.update({key: val})
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple solution for this! Thank you so much :) I will mark as accepted once the 10 minute delay is passed.

Answer (score 2):

[`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) uses keyword arguments to update dictionary, or dictionary or iterable of pairs. You can just pass your dictionary as the first argument:

```
new_dict.update(my_dict)
```

`update` designed to work with several keys at once. If you just want to set single value, you can just set the value:

```
new_dict[key] = value
```

Comment: I suppose this would work as well. I initially decided on the loop because I wanted to invoke some conditionals depending on which keys were present in `my_dict`(for instance `if key == 'timepoint': do something`)

Comment: Then you can just use `new_dict[key] = value`

Comment: So, are there any benefits to using either `update` or `new_dict[key] = value`?

Comment: They are the same if you are setting single element

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code for the `update` method, so you can see why it behaves the way it does (it is not the real source code, just an example):

```
def update(self, other_dict={}, **kwargs):
    for k, v in other_dict.items():
        self[k] = v
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        self[k] = v
```

So if you call `new_dict.update(key=val)` your `kwargs` will be equal to `{"key": value}`.

You need to pass your arguments inside a dictionary if you want to dinamically set the new keys.

Comment: Well, I also tried using `new_dict.update(dict(key=val))` which gave the same result. Would it have worked if I used a colon instead of an equal?

Comment: `dict(key=val)` creates a dictionary `{"key": val}`, with "key" as a string, that's why it gives you the same value. If you do `new_dict.update({key: val})` it will behave as you want.